# how to create alphabetical order in column of data list asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am tried to create a data list display all cuisine in alphabetical order in column however i couldn't find the way to do it, can any one help.

using data list or repeater in asp.net only allow you to display in horizontal or vertical alphabetical order for example

```
Afghan       Asian       Burmese     Cambodian
Chinese     Croatian    European    French
Greek            Indian     International   Italian
```

What I want to have is

```
Afghan      Chinese      Greek
Asian       Croatian     Indian 
Burmese     European     International 
Cambodian   French       Italian
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

nickf's answer helped me come to the following method that will transform a list as needed:

```
public static List<T> ReorderListIntoColumns<T>(List<T> list, int totalColumns)
    {
        List<T> reordered = new List<T>();
        int itemsPerColumn = (int) list.Count / totalColumns;

        for (int i = 0; i < itemsPerColumn; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < totalColumns; j++)
            {
                reordered.Add(list[(j * itemsPerColumn) + i]);
            }
        }

        return reordered;
    }
```

This topic seems to get a lot of views even though there was no accepted answer.  Hopefully this will help someone else out that needs to reorder a list in this way!

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is get your list in alphabetical order, and then rearrange such that when you use the datalist/repeater default ordering, it's in your desired format.

In bizarre pseudo-code.

```
/*
your input is A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L

given this order, it returns:

A, B, C
D, E, F
G, H, I
J, K, L

but you want

A, E, I
B, F, J
C, G, K
D, H, L

So you need to change your input to this:

A,E,I,B,F,J,C,G,K,D,H,L

*/

let numColumns = 3;
let numItems = 12;
let itemsPerColumn = numItems / numColumns;

loop i from 0 to itemsPerColumn - 1
    loop j from 0 to numColumns - 1
        newOrdering.push(oldOrdering[i * numColumns + j])
```

There might be some nifty .NET feature to change the ordering style, but this is just one old-school method.

PS: This is working on the best case scenario, which is that the number of items is evenly divisible by the number of columns. You'll have to adjust somewhat for different values.

Answer (score 0):

I recently accomplished this using a `PlaceHolder` and a custom table:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="locationTablePlaceHolder" runat="server"/>
```

Then in the backing code:

```
DataView view  = locations.Tables[0].DefaultView;
view.Sort      = "locationName";

Table table = new Table();
locationTablePlaceHolder.Controls.Clear();
locationTablePlaceHolder.Controls.Add(table);

// enumerator to loop through all items in the DataView
IEnumerator enumerator = view.GetEnumerator();
enumerator.Reset();

// first create all the row objects since we want to populate
// column by column.
int rowCount = 5;
int colCount = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}

// then loop through each column taking items from the enumerator
// to populate the table
for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            Label label = new Label();
            label.Text = (String)((DataRowView)enumerator.Current).Row["locationName"];
            cell.Controls.Add(label);
            table.Rows[i].Cells.Add(cell);
        }
    }
}
```